# FE and clustered standard errors for a panel with firms, industries and years

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, clustered-standard-errors

I have an unbalanced panel of firms, years and industries.

(1) At the moment I am running a panel regression with years and industries FE. My understanding is that I am counting for any omitted variables across the two dimensions (time and industries). In this situation, I feel that I do not need to control for clustered errors but I am not sure. Any insight?

(2) Say, I run a panel with firm FE and years. Since certain dynamics in industries may affect within group variation, I am assuming that this is the case when I should also count for clustered SE for industries, but not for years because I am already controlling for any year specific variation. Am I right for thinking this?

(3) Finally, if I run a panel with firm FE only, I should control for industry cluster SE but also time cluster SE, right? I am assuming that this is needed because there could be some unexplained variation in the dependent variable that is correlated over time as well as within each industry.

I appreciate any help that you can give me in order to clarify these three particular situations. Thank you in advance for your help!